# multiple virtual host working only for 2 subdomain in apache centos 6

Tags: centos6, apache2

Hi below is the content of httpd.conf file. I create 5 subdomain inside this file 2 subdomain are working. I mention after virtual host which are working and which are not working

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 88.198.133.25
DocumentRoot "/home/developer/public_html"
<Directory /home/developer/public_html>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>


# this is for default acees of apache
# working 


</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName bioad.log.com
DocumentRoot "/home/developer/public_html/subdomain/bio/bioad"
<Directory /home/developer/public_html/subdomain/bio/bioad>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#not working

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/developer/public_html/gecautonew
ServerName gec.log.com
ServerAlias gec.log.com
<Directory /home/developer/public_html/gecautonew>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#not working

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/developer/public_html/obb/public
ServerName obb.log.com
<Directory /home/developer/public_html/obb/public>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# working

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/developer/public_html/subd/bio/api
ServerName biopi.log.com
<Directory /home/developer/public_html/subd/bio/api>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#working

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/developer/public_html/biouser
ServerName biou.log.com
<Directory /home/developer/public_html/biouser>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#not working
```

I am unable to identify what is the actual problem in this config file

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which apache version you may need to add the NamedVirtualHost directive to the apache configuration and reload apache.

Please confirm you have the following in `/etc/httpd/config/httpd.conf` :
`NameVirtualHost *:80`